# No module named 'module.module_name' ; 'module_1' is not a package

Tags: python

Есть структура проекта:

```
prj_folder
  folder_1
    __init__.py
    scripts.py
    folder_2
      __init__.py
      engine.py
```

я пытаюсь вызвать функцию, которая находится в scripts.py, из файла engine.py:

```
from folder_1.scripts import func1
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1.scripts'; 'engine.py' is not a package
```

как её исправить?

*в scripts.py находятся только функции

Comment: Думаю, если folder_2 перемести в prj_folder, то это поможет найти пакет `folder_1`. Еще можно не меняя текущую структуру вызвать в `engine.py` `sys.path.append('..')` до импорта `folder_1`, но костыльно

Comment: я пробовал перенести engine.py в folder_1 и появилась другая ошибка: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
и пробовал делать sys.append('C:\prj_folder\folder_1')
ошибка не изменилась"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1.scripts'; 'engine.py' is not a package"

Comment: У вас путь, скорее всего, невалидный, т.к. этот слеш \ экранирует `p`, используйте строку с `r` -- r'C:\prj_folder\folder_1'  или другой слеш -- /

Comment: всё равно такая же ошибка.. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1.scripts'; 'engine.py' is not a package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `sys.path` работает (но мне кажется это все-же костыльно).

```
prj_folder/
    folder_1/
        __init__.py
        scripts.py
    folder_2/
        __init__.py
        engine.py
```

В `scripts.py`:

```
def func1():
    pass
```

В `engine.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from folder_1.scripts import func1
```